# About Andrica's and Cramer's conjectures

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

this question is moreorless related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57069/a-limit-involving-prime-numbers.
For $N$ a positive integer, let's define the set $A(N)$ as $\{m, \ \ \forall n\geq N, \ \ g_{n}:=(p_{n+1}-p_{n})<(\log p_{n})^{m}\}$. Let's assume that for all positive integer $H$, $A(H)$ is a non empty set. Then for any given positive integer $N$, $A(N)$ admits an infimum $m_{0}(N)$.

Let's furthermore assume Andrica's conjecture. This conjecture states that $\forall n>0, \ \ g_{n}<2\sqrt{p_{n}}+1$.
Due to the fact that $m_{0}(N)$ is the infimum of $A(N)$, there exists an integer $k\geq N$ such that $g_{k}=(\log p_{k})^{m_{0}(N)}$.
Now, suppose that $\forall n\geq N, \ \ (\log p_{n})^{m_{0}(N)}<2\sqrt{p_{n}}+1$. 
Equivalently, $\forall x\geq p_{N}, \ \ (\log x)^{m_{0}(N)}\lt 2\sqrt{x}+1$.
So $\forall x\geq p_{N}, \ \ \log ((\log x)^{m_{0}(N)})\lt \log (2\sqrt{x}+1)$.`
Equivalently $\forall x\geq p_{N}, \ \ m_{0}(N)\log \log x\lt \log 2+\log (\sqrt{x}+1/2)$ and finally $\forall x\geq p_{N}, \ \ m_{0}(N)\lt \frac{\log 2+\log (\sqrt{x}+1/2)}{\log \log x}$.

As $m_{0}(N)$ doesn't depend on $x$ this means that $\forall x\geq p_{N},\ \ \frac{\log 2+\log (\sqrt{x}+1/2)}{\log \log x}\gt m_{0}(N)$. 
So one has $m_{0}(N)\lt y_{0}$, where $y_{0}=1.98772705...$ is the minimum of the function $f:x\gt e\mapsto \dfrac{\log 2+\log(\sqrt{x}+1/2)}{\log\log x}$, provided $p_{N}\lt x_{0}$ (where $x_{0}$ is such that $y_{0}=f(x_{0})$). As $67\lt x_{0}\lt 68$, one gets $N\leq 19$.

Furthermore, as $g_{n}\geq 2$, one must have $(\log p_{n})^{m_{0}(N)}\geq 2$. Since $m_{0}(N)>1$, one can take $n$ such that $\log p_{n}\geq 2$, hence $n\geq 5$. So that if for all integer $N$ $A(N)$ is a non empty set, and if Andrica's conjecture holds true, then (a stronger form of) Cramer's conjecture holds true, namely $c=0$, with $c$ defined in the link given at the beginning of this post.

Edit: I think I took Gerhard Paseman and quid's comments into account.
So, is the proof correct now? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't the pk more relevant than the pN, and why should this by less than x0 and what if it is not? In any case, from a meta point of view this can hardly work. Also, you might consider recalling Cramer's conjecture rather then linking to it in a mildly confusing way. Finally, this is a slightly off-topic use of MO. Voting to close, at least in the current form.

Comment: I also think the proof is not valid.  I don't see why "one has $m_0(N) \lt y_0$ ", unless $y_0$ were a maximum.   Gerhard "Sometimes Knows Where Up Is" Paseman, 2011.08.15

Comment: There are two other places where I think gaps reside.  The most important one is that you need a nonempty set for any N in order to talk about the stuff relating to the conjecture, so this is already assuming something stronger (asymptotically) than Andrica's conjecture.  Although I disagree with quid about the question being off-topic, the question in its current form is not suitable for MathOverflow.  I recommend re-editing before reconsidering.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.15

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman: are you now convinced that one has $m_{0}(N)<y_{0}$ ?

Comment: Nope. Still has gaps.  Just because a power of a log of x is less than a multiple of sqrt(x) for all x > N does not mean you can now pull N down to 69.  You still can't assert that m_0 is less than y_0 on the basis of your reasoning.  On your next revision, pretend there is a prime p_n such that g_n is between 3.4 log p_n and 3.5 log p_n, while still having Andrica's conjecture hold.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.15

Comment: Sorry, I mean log p_n raised to some power between 3.4 and 3.5.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.15

Comment: Here is a version I could accept.  Suppose m_0 exists for some N.  Then for all positive n, there is m_1 > m_0 such that p_{n+1} < p_n + (log p_n)^{m_1}.  If m_1 happens to be less than 2, then both Cramer's model and (with further inspection) Andrica's conjecture hold.  However, while I believe m_0 exists, I do not have a proof.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.15 

Comment: In the above, I should take care to exclude the case of p_n=2.
Gerhard "Remember Those Troublesome Even Primes" Paseman, 2011.08.15 

Comment: Doing good maths is pretty hard...Well, if I replace $\forall n\gt N$ by $\exists N, \ \ \forall n>0$, is it ok?

Comment: I'm sure the replacement is good for some things.  If you are trying for a proof that andrica plus something implies cramers, I think the something alone will imply cramers.  If you need more specifics than I have presented here, I invite you to try meta or find my email address.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.15

Comment: Perhaps my first comment was not good/to the point. You basically never use that the p_n are the primes; except perhaps for very small ones. So, this can never work. Take other sets, coinciding with the primes up to 10000000 or whathever and then containing every (log x)^t number for t=1,2,3,4 or something. Why doesn't your argument work also here, where it obvioulsy can't always yield the same thing. Moroever, note that Cramérs model predicts c=1 (likely wrongly), so if you want 0 (also likley wrong but who knows), you need to use something quite subtle on the primes.

Comment: @quid: I think Cramer's model predicts $\lim \sup \frac{g_{n}}{(\log p_{n})^2}=1$, not $\lim \frac{g_{n}}{(\log p_{n})^2}=1$.

Comment: Yes, the limsup or more or less the best constant in the big Oh; I thought this was the c. Sorry for the confusion, but I warned you the def of c is confusing. But what does this change? If you want to sttudy the limit you need to be able to deal with the limsup. The limit itself should not exist. The liminf is 0. Even liminf g_n/log n is 0 (Goldston, Pintz, Yildirim); and TwinPrimes predicts a subsequence of g_n constant 2. In any case, if ever you want to show the limit is 0 (but note it is likely wrong!) you'd need to use something on the primes which is not in Cramérs model.  